# Can't change drawer icon for NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation, drawer, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement the new `NavigationDrawer` provided since the last Android keynote.

I got everything up and running, the navigation drawer opens and closes when pressing on the icon on the top left corner.

But now I still have the arrow icon although I replaced it with the ic_drawer from Android.  Why?

Here's my code where I specified the icon:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                 
            mDrawerLayout,         
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //<-- This is the icon provided by Google itself
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close 
            )
```

But the application still runs with the standard icon of `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I just got the Navigation Drawer working.  I had forgotten to add following methods also provided by the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) examples:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: This was it exactly! Thank you! I was looking for like 2 hours for a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, but just with older devices, like 2.3. My code was already like yours and the problem keeps disturbing me..

Comment: So those times when you're following an official Google example and say, "Oh, I don't need implement those functions yet".  Yeah, don't do that.  Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem the answer is if you are setting

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

then the normal up icon is shown. So try without using it